# How do I export hive query result to google cloud storage bucket as a CSV from GCE

Tags: hive, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, hiveql

I have a query that writes the query result to a CSV file:

```
hive -e 'select * from transactions limit 50'>abc.csv
```

so the result will be stored in **abc.csv** which is available only in that gcp instance.

But I need to export it into a GCS bucket so that later I can dump it into  BigQuery.

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
hive -e 'select * from transactions limit 50'>gs://my-bucket/abc.csv
```

so, how can I store my hive query result in a GCS bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the hive query to your instance then use the `gsutil` command to move it to your bucket.

`gsutil mv abc.csv gs://my-bucket/abc.csv`

If you do not have gsutil installed on your instance, follow the steps provided here: [Install gsutil | Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install)

To find out more about using storage buckets with instances, you can refer to the google docs: [Connecting to Cloud Storage buckets](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets)

An alternative would be to mount your cloud storage bucket within your instance allowing you to write the hive query result directly to your bucket.

To do this, you will need to make use of Cloud Storage FUSE, you can follow the steps here to install it: [Cloud Storage FUSE | Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#using)

Comment: thanks, @Nickson Thanda I have installed cloud storage fuse and it is working good

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below Query,

```
insert overwrite  directory 'gs://bucket-name/file_name/' row format delimited \
fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile \
select * from <db_name>.<table_name> limit 10;
```

The above query will put the result into the specified bucket location in a file whose format will be CSV.

Comment: This works too. However, the output I see is in .snappy format and not CSV. Aman, can you please suggest what I can do to get a csv output?